# How to export a Ruby Array from my Heroku console into CSV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, heroku

I am looking to export an array from my heroku console into a local CSV file.

In my current situation, I have a daily rake task which looks for tweets talking about my application. I'd like to analyse those tweets to see at what time they came in, etc:

```
heroku run console
tweets = Tweet.all
code to export tweets into a local CSV file goes here
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Sergio! What do you mean if I can write text file?

Comment: If you know how to write text files, then writing tweets to CSV file should be no problem.

Comment: I don't know how to write text files from the Heroku console into my local machine. Would you mind telling me how to do so?

Comment: I don't use heroku (or its console), so I don't know if it allows you access your local filesystem or not. At the very least you can print this CSV to the terminal and copy/paste it to your local file. I'd create a "private" url which would allow me to download that CSV.

Comment: You can't save files at all on the Heroku server as there is no "real" filesystem. You'd need to save them to S3 or some other cloud storage provider.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I followed this railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel and added a way to export to excel from an admin panel. Thanks again.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't access your local filesystem from the heroku console. One option is to use [Tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29). Tee sends the output to both STDOUT and a file, so you can have a local log of everything that was printed.

```
heroku run console | tee output.txt
```

Comment: This freezes on `Running 'console' attached to terminal... up, run.4296`... does it work for anyone?  (edit: formatting)

Comment: @ErikTrautman I think you're right. This doesn't seem to work with the latest heroku client.

Comment: This worked for me with the latest heroku client, BUT I couldn't see anything I was typing. I entered my commands blindly and then `exit`, and upon viewing output.txt it was all there (both my input and the desired output).

Answer (score 20):

I tried using Tee as suggested and also got stuck at

```
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.4165
```

I ended up running an SSH shell to localhost and then piped it through tee.

```
$ ssh localhost | tee output.txt
$ heroku run console
```

Might not be the best solution, but it worked for me.

Comment: Why would that actually solve it?! 
I'd rather actually mimic the effect but without running an ssh server on my desktop.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you for the suggestion. I'm using OSX. To ssh to localhost, I had to enable 'Remote Login' under System Preference >> Sharing.

Answer (score 6):

FWIW you could pretty easily puts a string with commas and newlines and then copy paste into your text editor and save as .csv, though "all of the tweets" might be a little unwieldy.

```
tweets = Tweet.all
@string = String.new()
@string << Tweet.last.attributes.keys.join(", ") + "\n" # "header" row with attribute names


tweets.each do |t|
  @string << t.attributes.values.join(", ") + "\n"
end

puts @string #will output string with \n newline which you could then copy paste into your editor and save as a csv
```

Comment: Combine this with File.new('Filename.csv','w') and you can easily add the csv output to a file. Saved me a bunch of time, and you can use it on any rails server.

Comment: One problem with copy/paste is if you're trying to capture enough data that it scrolls off the top of the heroku console.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Taps to export the db to your local machine, then operate on it there: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps

Answer (score 1):

You can shell out to SCP:

```
my_data = "hello world"
File.write("tmp/data", my_data)
`scp tmp/data me@some-server:`
```

It may prompt you about the server being unknown and ask for a password.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `rails runner` to run a line of code or three on heroku and pipe (or tee) the results to a file:

```
heroku run rails runner \'Tweet.all.to_csv\' -a my-app-name | all_tweets.csv
```

You can disable rails logging if that's showing up in your file and trim the top of the file if you're getting startup logging like "Running `rails runner`" in your file, but that should be easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Ruby on your Heroku instance:

`echo 'p User.first' | heroku run --no-tty 'ruby -W0 -r ./config/environment' > output.txt`

This will print the first user to the `output.txt` file.

Also you can run a local script on Heroku by piping it to the stdin.

`cat my_script.rb | heroku run --no-tty 'ruby -W0 -r ./config/environment' > output.txt`

Note that it's possible that you'll get some unwanted text (like warnings) that will appear at the beginning of the `output.txt` file. You will have to trim it manually or by using a trimming command such as:

`tail -n +4 -f` that will not print the first 4 lines.

Here is the full example:

`cat my_script.rb | heroku run --no-tty 'ruby -W0 -r ./config/environment' | tail -n +4 -f > output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I tried Tee as suggested, but for some reason it always got stuck after the output of

```
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.1
```

So I ended up emailing the csv content for me in the text format email body. If you already have emailing set up, that can be easy solution too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Gnomet, mind sharing how you'd go ahead and do that?

Comment: We have a Rails app with a Mailer set up to mail users. So I added there a method that just send the contents of given variable to the user. So in the example below there's PersonMailer that has method free_content_message(email, content).

csv_content = method_that_returns_the_csv_you_want
PersonMailer.free_content_message("me@example.com", csv_content).deliver

I haven't been sending mail without Rails mailers, so can't give more general advice now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following steps with the new heroku console.I was able to get the logs.

1. type command 
   script output.txt
   (this creates a file named output.txt for saving terminal logs)
2. open heroku console and execute commands.
3. when you are done type ctrl + d.

Terminal logs are saved in output.txt file.