# Bypassing --More-- in Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, console

I would like to analyze all the posts created by users of my Rails App, which is hosted on Heroku.  In the console, I created a variable that contains every word ever posted on the site, which accounts for hundreds of thousands of words.  I'd like to export these words from the console to do analysis elsewhere.

I've read from this post that using Tee enables you to get a copy of the output of your console:

[How to export a Ruby Array from my Heroku console into CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774167/how-to-export-a-ruby-array-from-my-heroku-console-into-csv)

The problem is that if I try to print all the words, the console always shows '--More--', at which point I press the enter key to reveal more of the text.  As you can imagine, for hundreds of thousands of words, it would be impractical for me to keep pressing enter to reveal the entirety of the text.  How can I bypass this?

Comment: get a db dump and load it locally.  then use the rails console locally to create your csv.  or you can also expose an endpoint in your application which will create this csv for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku run console | tee output.txt
```

If you're using `tee`-trick above, you can just type `q` to exit your terminal pager program (I assume it's [`more`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command))) since `tee` writes simultaneously into the standard out (that's why you're seeing all the output and `more` automatically starts to page it) and to the file you gave it on the argument (`output.txt` in the case above).

Since you don't need/want to view all the output, just quit `more` and do what you want with the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a plain old unix shell redirect?

```
heroku run console > output.txt
```

Probably is is better to write a rake task to output your data, so that is not mixed with other things that happen in the console. When you just use stdout (for example puts), then something like this should work:

```
heroku rake db:postexport > output.txt
```